# Ruby Regex Complex Numbers

Tags: ruby, regex

I have the below code for testing for complex numbers:

```
module RegexPractice

  def get_complex(input)
    return input =~ /.*i*/
  end

end
```

The code should pass each of the unit tests below, but mine is failing beginning with unit test #7. I'm unsure of an implementation to address this. Any ideas?

```
def test_complex

  #1
  assert_equal(0, RegexPractice.get_complex("4i"))
  #2
  assert_equal(0, RegexPractice.get_complex("43i"))
  #3
  assert_equal(0, RegexPractice.get_complex("-46i"))
  #4
  assert_equal(0, RegexPractice.get_complex("+46i"))
  #5
  assert_equal(0, RegexPractice.get_complex("35+46i"))
  #6
  assert_equal(0, RegexPractice.get_complex("3-46i"))
  #7
  assert_equal(5, RegexPractice.get_complex("num: -35+46i"))
  #8
  assert_equal(0, RegexPractice.get_complex("+3-46i"))
  #9
  assert_equal(nil, RegexPractice.get_complex("abi"))
  #10
  assert_equal(nil, RegexPractice.get_complex("65"))
end
```

Comment: `"num: -35+46i" =~ /.*i*/`
`=> 0 `

Comment: Why did you edit the failing test? Which version is correct behaviour? I wrote my response based on the original, and your question was based on a **failing** test.

Comment: @TomLord After reviewing the code, I thought I had made a mistake, but the test was correct originally. Post has been edited to reflect this

Comment: What is the significance of `get_complex` returning 5? Or 0? Or `nil`? Are you testing that the string is a complex number? Then return a boolean rather than whatever the regex happens to return (the index of the first match), `input =~ /regex/ ? true : false`, and call it `is_complex?`. If you're trying to extract the complex number, use [capture groups](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Capturing) and return what is captured.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could implement it like this:

```
module RegexPractice

  def get_complex(input)
    input =~ /[+-]?\d*[+-]?\d*i/
  end

end
```

The issue is that you're not being strict enough about what may come before the `i`, as part of the complex number.

Your current code is just saying "include *anything* before `i` as part of the match". Therefore the match *always* begins at the start of the string - so the method returns `0` (or `nil` if there's no match).

To explain my regex:

- `[+-]` means "either a `+` or `-` character.
- `[+-]?` means "zero or one of the above".
- `\d` means "any digit" (0, 1, 2, ..., 9).
- `\d*` means "zero or more of the above".

So in other words, this will match anything like:

- `"42i"`
- `"2-i"`
- `"-3+9i"`

But *won't* match arbitrary other strings that contain an `i`.

---

Your tests #9 and #10 also fail (but pass with my implementation!) - but you are not seeing this, because the test terminates upon its first failure. (It would be better to split each assertion into a separate test, for this reason.)

```
assert_equal(nil, RegexPractice.get_complex("abi"))
```

Your method will return `0`, because it still just matches "anything followed by `i`".

My method will return `nil`, because it only matches "numbers" followed by `i` (e.g. `-3+4i`); not arbitrary characters.

```
assert_equal(nil, RegexPractice.get_complex("65"))
```

Your method *should* work here, except for a small mistake: Because your regex ends in `i*` instead of just `i`, it matches "0 or more `i`s". In other words, it will still match strings that *don't* contain an `i`.

My method does not have this mistake.

---

Normally however, if you want to convert a string to a complex number, you could just do:

```
Complex(string)
```

...And if that raises an exception, then the string was an invalid format.

Inputs like `"num: -35+46i"` would normally be invalid however; so if you want to accept these then you do indeed need to perform some sort of regex lookup first.

Comment: Thank you for the in-depth answer, Tom. I have attempted your implementation and test #9 is still failing, outputting '2' rather than 'nil'

Comment: Ahh wait, yeah. That's because I have all chars before the `i` marked as optional. A perfect answer to this could be a bit more complicated, but to keep it simple can we assume that there **must** be a digit before `i`? This would mean e.g. `2+i` gets interpreted as invalid unfortunately, but `2+1i` would work.

Comment: Or to put it another way, can you clarify the validity rules? Why is `abi` invalid, but `num: i` valid? (Or is that invalid too?) Is `ab i` valid? Is the rule "There must be a space between the complex number and other text"?

Comment: In the case of the latter, you could use `/(?<=^| )[+-]?\d*[+-]?\d*i.*/`

Comment: `/(?<=^| )[+-]?\d*[+-]?\d*i.*/` did the trick. Thank you for your explanation, Tom, it makes much more sense now!

Answer (score 1):

The reason your test is failing is that you may be testing for the wrong thing.

`RegexPractice.get_complex("num: -35+46i")` is *supposed* to return 0, because the pattern you're matching with:

`/.*i*/`

returns the first index of the complete match of `0 or more of any character` followed by `0 or more i's`.

You can use [Rubular](http://rubular.com/) to live-check your regex matching, or you can run it in a console:

`irb >>> "num: -35+46i" =~ /.*i/
=> 0`

If you are ultimately trying to return the first index of the complex number in any given string, you may need to do some more complex pattern matching depending on your expected input, i.e. look for a `+` or `-` sign with a real number on the left and a complex number on the right of it.

Finally, if you want to just create and interact with Complex numbers you may want to refer to [this documentation.](https://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Complex.html)

Comment: Your reasoning doesn't really make sense... "Your test is wrong, because it is failing"?! Maybe the tests are *correct*, and OP is looking for a correct alternate implementation of the method?

Comment: @TomLord I like your answer better! Thanks for the input. I don't mean to offend, I just wasn't sure what OP meant by "testing for complex numbers".